GNU make: how to count the up-to-date targets?
I'd like to display a progress bar during building with GNU make. It works great for clean builds, but it's inaccurate for incremental builds.
To calculate the actual progress, we need to know the total number of files to compile and that how many were already compiled.
The issue is getting the number of files to build. It's easy to count ALL the files, but in case of an incremental build, when only a fraction of the targets are out-of-date, the calculation does not work.
Is it somehow possible to count the number of out-of-date targets before starting executing the rules? Alternatively, counting the up-to-date targets would be just as good.
Here is the current code (simplified), showing how the progress is calculated:
define ADD_TO_COMPILE
$1 : $2
    $(eval ALL_STEPS+=1)
    $$(eval FILES_DONE+=1)
    $$(call CALL_CC,$1,$2)
$(1:.$(OBJ_FILE_SUFFIX)=.$(DEP_FILE_SUFFIX)): ;
include $(1:.$(OBJ_FILE_SUFFIX)=.$(DEP_FILE_SUFFIX))
endef

This function is invoked for each C file in the project.
ALL_STEPS is incremented during interpreting the makefile, and when rule execution begins it contains the number of ALL files, both up-to-date and out-of-date ones.
FILES_DONE is incremented as the recipes are executed. It always reflects how many files were compiled during the current run, but not that how many were up-to-date and did not need recompilation.
So I can display files_built_in_the_current_run / total_files, and it's wildly inaccurate when only 2 files from 100 need to be built. Indicator goes up to 2%, and we're done!
Any ideas?

It is not possible.  If it were, GNU Make could do that itself.  But the way make works is that it starts building things and keeps going until there's nothing left to build, then it stops.  It does not make a plan of all the things that need to be built, then run that plan.
So, when make is in the middle of building it has no idea whether the target it's building is the last one that will need to be built, or there are still 100's more to go.
The only way to do something like this would be to first run make -n and count how many things were built, then use that as the total.  Note, though, that this is not accurate since it's very possible, depending on how the makefile is constructed and what the recipes do, that the real build could build more or fewer targets than make -n shows.

Hey! Long time no talk. I'm considering adding a dummy prerequisite that's always updated, and in the recipe check whether only that triggered the rule. If so, do nothing, just increment the counter. Might affect performance or might not be possible... Just thinking out loud.

That won't work.  Make will only ever build a given target one time no matter how many times it's listed as a prerequisite.  But also, I'm not sure I see what the goal if it would be; it would still not show you how many targets you have not yet built or provide the total number of targets that are to be built...?

The idea is that it will execute ALL recipes, but in the recipe I check whether only the dummy prerequisite triggered the recipe (by checking $$?) or it really has to be rebuilt. If only the dummy triggered, I count that the file was processed, but do not build it. Eventually the counter would go up to the total number of files and the progress bar would indicate correct percentage. I agree that it's a weird idea but will give it a try... Because I have no better idea at all. Btw what would you recommend instead of make?

I see.  It could work although I don't know what the performance impact would be.  I don't have any great advice for alternatives.  There are many but they all have other downsides.  The most popular is probably CMake which is not actually a build tool but more like a "build tool file generator".  It can create makefiles for you (or, if you prefer, files for other build tools like Ninja)  The makefiles that cmake generates DO have a way of tracking percent complete.  CMake-generated makefiles just assign a value to each target so if you skip lots your percent jumps up.

The problem with tools like CMake is that what they can do is severely circumscribed by the fact that they need to generate control files for so many different build tools.  It handles "normal" things easily but it is a lot more difficult to do certain things which can be trivially accomplished in make.  But maybe you don't care about those kinds of things.

Okay, thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know the performance penalty and whether it worked at all. We do a lot of weird stuff (invoking AUTOSAR code generators etc...). CMake is not a good fit. Do you know how the cmake-generated makefiles calculate the progress during incremental builds? How do they know that a target is skipped?

I'm not sure exactly how it works, but CMake has an advantage in that it generates the makefile.  So it knows the total number of possible targets and it knows the order in which targets are listed as prerequisites, before it writes any makefiles.  So it can (and does, in some way) hardcode this information into the makefiles as they are created.

I'm also generating all rules (with metaprogramming) and exactly know the total number of targets. I've seen attempts to do this in makefiles by "manually" comparing the dates in the interpretation phase by issuing shell commands, but that's very cumbersome and slow. What I'm missing is not some static information, but that what's the state of the targets on the disk after a previous build and user edited some files etc... That cannot be hard-coded in the makefile.

Why do you need to know that?  If you know you have 500 targets and you know that this target being built is target #100, then you know you're 20% done and you can report that.  It doesn't matter how many targets you've built or not built, you know you've "looked at" 100 of them and you haven't yet "looked at" 400 of them.  If the next one that's built is #400, then you report 80% done.  It jumps from 20% to 80%, but that's correct, for at least some definition of "correct".

In other words the percentage tells you how many targets you've considered.  It doesn't tell you how many you've built, or will build.  It could be you jump from 0% to 20% to 80%, then you start building things and go 81%, 82%, 83%, etc.  So you can't use it to estimate how many more recipes will RUN but you can use it to estimate how many more recipes will be CONSIDERED.

Okay, got you. But that only works if the targets are always built in the same order? If you run make --shuffle, the order is randomized. We can figure that we're building target #123, but make may build that first, then #1, #2, #573 etc... But this is a great idea anyway and might be the solution! I simply fix the order, assign indexes to each target, and that index will be the actual progress. Thanks man I need to test this, Friday or not. Have a great weekend, will update you later!

Correct you cannot use shuffle mode with this, and still get accurate results.

Okay, it works perfectly without shuffle! Thanks for the idea again. I guess I create an answer. You're really good, helped me with so many make issues! Thanks again.

Thanks to @MadScientist for pointing out how CMake does this: when generating the rules, the progress (index of the files) are assigned to rule-specific variables. When executing the rules, the rule-specific variables can be reported as the actual progress. The solution works with acceptable limitations:

--shuffle does not work. If the rule execution order is randomized, progress will also jump rendomly back and forth. It's assumed that rules are executed in the same order as they were defined.
During incremental builds the progress bar is not advancing linearly
with time, but at least it goes through to the end, possibly with
large jumps when many consecutive files are up-to-date.

The code looks something like this (unnecessary details removed):
define ADD_TO_COMPILE
$(eval ALL_STEPS+=1)
$1 : PROGR := $(words $(ALL_STEPS))
$1 : $2
    $(call PROGRESS_BAR,$$(PROGR)
    $$(call CALL_CC,$1,$2)
$(1:.$(OBJ_FILE_SUFFIX)=.$(DEP_FILE_SUFFIX)): ;
include $(1:.$(OBJ_FILE_SUFFIX)=.$(DEP_FILE_SUFFIX))
endef

It's even simpler and more elegant than my previous attempts. Thanks to @MadScientist for his continuous support and great ideas!
